# Can someone please explain this bit manipulation code to me?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I am new to competitive programming. I recently gave the Div 3 contest codeforces. Eventhough I solved the problem C, I really found this code from one of the top programmers really interesting. I have been trying to really understand his code, but it seems like I am too much of a beginner to understand it without someone else explaining it to me.

Here is the code.

```
void main(){
    int S;
    cin >> S;
    int ans = 1e9;
 
    for (int mask = 0; mask < 1 << 9; mask++) {
        int sum = 0;
        string num;
 
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            if (mask >> i & 1) {
                sum += i + 1;
                num += char('0' + (i + 1));
            }
 
        if (sum != S)
            continue;
 
        ans = min(ans, stoi(num));
    }
 
    cout << ans << '\n';
}
```

The problem is to find the minimum number whose sum of digits is equal to given number S, such that every digit in the result is unique.

Eq. S = 20,
Ans = 389 (3+8+9 = 20)

Comment: Agreed. This is an interesting snippet to understand how bitmasking works, but it's a less good solution (slower, harder to understand) than something more simple, like just subtracting 9, then 8, then 7, etc from the target sum, and outputting those digits in reverse order. And it's certainly not how the majority of production code works in the real world.

Comment: *I am new to competitive programming.* I suggest that you remain new to that subject, by immediately stopping this and learn from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242).

Comment: Agreed. No production grade code uses such structure of programming. However, I see it as a great engagement and good way to improve my skills on data structures and algorithms by doing these challenges.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with puzzle programming, and it can be very beneficial, but the culture surrounding it produces notably bad code (for professional environments at least.)  It's great to learn and understand _what_ the winning solutions do (abstractly) and to think in a solution-oriented way, and I like _codegolf_ because it forces you to think differently and obscurely.  But it's equally important to avoid incorporating "bad habits"--or at least be sure to compartmentalize them to not "bleed into" more serious code.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BiLB_Ivz9Pg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mask is 9-bits long, each bit represents a digit from 1-9.  Thus it counts from 0 and stops at 512.  Each value in that number corresponds to possible solution.  Find every solution that sums to the proper value, and remember the smallest one of them.

For example, if mask is 235, in binary it is

```
011101011   // bit representation of 235
987654321   // corresponding digit

==> 124678  // number for this example: "digits" with a 1-bit above
            // and with lowest digits to the left
```

There are a few observations:

- you want the smallest digits in the most significant places in the result, so a 1 will *always* come before any larger digit.
- there is no need for a zero in the answer; it doesn't affect the sum and only makes the result larger

This loop converts the bits into the corresponding digit, and applies that digit to the sum and to the "num" which is what it'll print for output.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        if (mask >> i & 1) {  // check bit i in the mask
            sum += i + 1;     // numeric sum
            num += char('0' + (i + 1));  // output as a string
        }
```

`(mask >> i)` ensures the `i`th bit is now shifted to the first place, and then `& 1` removes every bit except the first one.  The result is either 0 or 1, and it's the value of the `i`th bit.

The `num` could have been accumulated in an int instead of a string (initialized to 0, then for each digit: multiply by 10, then add the digit), which is more efficient, but they didn't.

Answer (score 1):

The way to understand what a snippet of code is doing is to A) understand what it does at a macro-level, which you have done and B) go through each line and understand what it does, then C) work your way backward and forward from what you know, gaining progress a bit at a time. Let me show you what I mean using your example.

Let's start by seeing, broadly (top-down) what the code is doing:

```
void main(){

    // Set up some initial state
    int S;
    cin >> S;
    int ans = 1e9;
 
    // Create a mask, that's neat, we'll look at this later.
    for (int mask = 0; mask < 1 << 9; mask++) {

        // Loop state
        int sum = 0;
        string num;
 
        // This loop seems to come up with candidate sums, somehow.
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            if (mask >> i & 1) {
                sum += i + 1;
                num += char('0' + (i + 1));
            }
 
        // Stop if the sum we've found isn't the target
        if (sum != S)
            continue;
 
        // Keep track of the smallest value we've seen so far
        ans = min(ans, stoi(num));
    }
 
    // Print out the smallest value
    cout << ans << '\n';
}
```

So, going from what we knew about the function at a macro level, we've found that there are really only two spots that are obscure, the two loops. (If anything outside of those are confusing to you, please clarify.)

So now let's try going bottom-up, line-by-line those loops.

```
// The number 9 appears often, it's probably meant to represent the digits 1-9
// The syntax 1 << 9 means 1 bitshifted 9 times.
// Each bitshift is a multiplication by 2.
// So this is equal to 1 * (2^9) or 512.
// Mask will be 9 bits long, and each combination of bits will be covered.
for (int mask = 0; mask < 1 << 9; mask++) {

  // Here's that number 9 again.
  // This time, we're looping from 0 to 8.
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

    // The syntax mask >> i shifts mask down by i bits.
    // This is like dividing mask by 2^i.
    // The syntax & 1 means get just the lowest bit.
    // Together, this returns true if mask's ith bit is 1, false if it's 0.
    if (mask >> i & 1) {

      // sum is the value of summing the digits together
      // So the mask seems to be telling us which digits to use.
      sum += i + 1;

      // num is the string representation of the number whose sum we're finding.
      // '0'+(i+1) is a way to convert numbers 1-9 into characters '1'-'9'.
      num += char('0' + (i + 1));
    }
  }
}
```

Now we know what the code is doing, but it's hard to figure out. Now we have to meet in the middle - combine our overall understanding of what the code does with the low-level understanding of the specific lines of code.

We know that this code gives up after 9 digits. Why? Because there are only 9 unique non-zero values (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9). The problem said they have to be unique.

Where's zero? Zero doesn't contribute. A number like 209 will always be smaller than its counterpart without the zero, 92 or 29. So we just don't even look at zero.

We also know that this code doesn't care about order. If digit 2 is in the number, it's always before digit 5. In other words, the code doesn't ever look at the number `52`, only `25`. Why? Because the smallest anagram number (numbers with the same digits in a different order) will always start with the smallest digit, then the second smallest, etc.

So, putting this all together:

```
void main(){
    // Read in the target sum S
    int S;
    cin >> S;

    // Set ans to be a value that's higher than anything possible
    // Because the largest number with unique digits is 987654321.
    int ans = 1e9;
 
    // Go through each combination of digits, from 1 to 9.
    for (int mask = 0; mask < 1 << 9; mask++) {
        int sum = 0;
        string num;
 
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            // If this combination includes the digit i+1,
            // Then add it to the sum, and append to the string representation.
            if (mask >> i & 1) {
                sum += i + 1;
                num += char('0' + (i + 1));
            }
 
        // If this combination does not yield the right sum, try the next combination.
        if (sum != S)
            continue;
 
        // If this combination does yield the right sum, 
        // see if it's smaller than our previous smallest.
        ans = min(ans, stoi(num));
    }
 
    // Print the smallest combination we found.
    cout << ans << '\n';
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Really great explanation. Could understand it much better when I printed the mask for every iteration where the sum of digits were equal to S.

Essentially, we are trying each combination of digits, where LSB is mapped to number 1 and MSB to number 9. We add the digits 'i' to the sum where (1 << i) is set and maintain the smallest answer.

I learned Bit Masking today. Thank you so much for the support!

Answer (score 1):

The for loop is iterating over all 9-digit binary numbers and turning those binary numbers into a string of decimal digits such that if *n*th binary digit is on then a *n*+1 digit is appended to the decimal number.

Generating the numbers this way ensures that the digits are unique and that zero never appears.

But as @Welbog mentions in comments this solution to the problem is way more complicated than it needs to be. The following will be an order of magnitude faster, and I think is clearer:

```
int smallest_number_with_unique_digits_summing_to_s(int s) {
    int tens = 1;
    int answer = 0;
    for (int n = 9; n > 0 && s > 0; --n) {
        if (s >= n) {
            answer += n * tens;
            tens *= 10;
            s -= n;
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick way to on how code works.

First you need to know sum of which digits equal to `S`. Since each digit is unique, you can assign a bit to them in a binary number like this:

```
Bit number    Digit
0             1
1             2
2             3
...
8             9
```

So you can check all numbers that are less than `1 << 9` (numbers with 9 bits corresponding 1 to 9) and check if sum of bits if equal to your sum based on their value. So for example if we assume `S=17`:

```
384 -> 1 1000 0000 -> bit 8 = digit 9 and bit 7 = digit 8 -> sum of digits = 8+9=17
```

Now that you know sum if correct, you can just create number based on digits you found.

Comment: `1<<9` is _much smaller_ than `1e9`

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis oops,misstypes. Edited.